# Autoscaling & Launchconfiguration not getting deleted on stack delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Im creating an AWS stack using cloudformation json,the issue is whenever i delete stack from cloudformation,the associated Autoscaling group & Launch configuration resources not getting deleted. I have to manually go to **Autoscaling groups** and delete the resources.(Auto scaling group and Launch configuration)

Comment: Are you associating the ASG and LC elsewhere after creation of the stack? Are you setting "DeletionPolicy" attribute to the resources at the time of creation of the stack?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Shibashis   DeletionPolicy is by Default "Delete" right?

Comment: Yes. That's the default policy

Comment: @Shibashis then it should delete when I delete cloud formation which is not happening sometimes

Comment: You dont configure the LC's anywhere outside the cloudformation right

Comment: @Shibashis yes I have configured inside cloud formation only..but when I delete cloud formation autoscaling group and launch configuration is not getting deleted sometimes..

Comment: I am not sure ab the issue. Reaching out aws support would not be a bad idea. In the past I have noticed the issue when I had associate an SG build in the cf template with an instance created outside teh CF template